# Compare Intel Galileo and Intel Edison

Tags: embedded, iot, intel-edison, intel-galileo, soc

I am quite new to the Internet of Things. I checked the Intel website and went through a few other links too. But I cannot clearly understand what is the difference between Intel Galileo and Intel Edison? And which one should be used when?

Does anyone know of a good resource for reference?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I will list key features of both

**Galileo**

- CPU: Intel Quark X1000 400 MHz
- RAM: 256 MB
- Storage: Micro SD Card

**Edison**

- CPU: A dual core, dual threaded Intel ATOM x86 CPU running at 500 MHz and a 32-bit Intel Quark Micro-controller running at 100 MHz.
- RAM: 1 GB
- Storage: 4 GB ROM + (micro SD card on Arduino board)
- Communication: Wi-Fi and Bluetooth LE.

**Summary**

- Edison is way more powerful in terms of CPU (ATOM vs Quark) and RAM.
- Edison is more flexible like while making prototype you can use it with Arduino board and while deploying you can use it with smaller breakout board required for your application.
- Almost all things that can be done using Galileo can be done better using Edison in very smaller form factor (correct me if i am wrong).

**Conclusion**

Difference between Galileo and Edison is 1 year of more research and technological advances by Intel.

Comment: Note that the CPU for Galileo (both GEN 1 and GEN 2) is a one core Quark.  The CPU for Edison is a two core Atom and more powerful.

Answer (score 34):

I work at Intel and may be able to help.

Intel(R) Edison is a product-ready, general-purpose compute platform optimized to enable rapid innovation and product development.Intel Edison is ideal for small form factor devices that require a powerful computing system.  Some good use cases are robots and quadcopters, 3D fabrication machines, remote asset monitoring, and audio processing.

Intel(R)  Galileo is an open source, Arduino-compatible platform that enables educators, students, and makers of all skill levels to quickly and easily engage in projects. It combines the simplicity of the Arduino development environment with the performance of Intel technology and the advanced capabilities of a full Linux software stack.

A really great place to learn more about both platforms is our online community at maker.intel.com.
You can join the conversation, find getting started guides, and share your projects in our project gallery.

Comment: Thanks - +1 . I was more looking for one on one compare eg: differnece between processing power, OS, sensors, limitations, memory, etc.

Comment: Can I use Intel(R) Galileo on Windows with .NetMF?